# Swift event listener for deleting items from tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, event-handling

I have a table view, where the user can add cells, which are stored into a database.
This tableview is enbeded in a navigation controllers, and the left bar button item is an "edit" item, which allows the user to delete the different cells, and when this happens, I would like to be able to save the cells still in the tableview to the database. The edit button is added programatically.